# For loop through custom filter results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-filter

I have a list of applications, I have a custom filter for getting the unique values of a specified field. I ng-repeat out checkboxes for each of these unique values to filter a table.

I need to for loop using the values returned by the unique filter. This is so I can have a button which unchecks all of the checkboxes returned in the ng-repeat.

I have it working but it loops through ALL of the tables values (which is thousands) instead of just for the unique values.

Markup:

```
    <div ng-repeat="cat in applications | unique : 'Category'">
       <label>
           <input name="abc" type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.FCategory[cat.Category]" ng-value="cat" ng-init="$parent.FCategory[cat.Category]=true">{{ cat.Category }}
       </label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" ng-click="uncheckAll()">Untick
```

JS, Unique Filter:

```
App.filter('unique', function () {
    return function (collection, keyname)
    {
        var output = [],
            keys = [];
        angular.forEach(collection, function (item) {
            var key = item[keyname];
            if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                keys.push(key);
                output.push(item);
            }
        });
        return output;
    };
});
```

JS, uncheck all function:

```
 $scope.uncheckAll = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.applications.length; i++) {
            var item = $scope.applications[i].Category;
           $scope.FCategory[item] = false;

        }
    };
```

The issue is 'for (var i = 0; i < $scope.applications.length; i++) {' loops for every single record, I can't figure out how to have   '$scope.applications.length' only be for the unique filter results.

The best I can come up with (which doesn't work) is...

```
$scope.uncheckAll = function () {
        var a = $scope.applications;

        for (var i = 0; i < $filter('unique')(a,'Category').length; i++) {
            var item = $scope.applications[i].Category;
           $scope.FCategory[item] = false;

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could solve this, is to store the filtered results in a new scope variable (uniqueApplications), which is then passed into your uncheckAll function:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in (uniqueApplications = (applications | unique : 'Category'))">
   <label>
       <input name="abc" type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.FCategory[cat.Category]" ng-value="cat" ng-init="$parent.FCategory[cat.Category]=true">{{ cat.Category }}
   </label>
</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="uncheckAll(uniqueApplications)">
```

You also need to modify your uncheckAll function:

```
$scope.uncheckAll = function (list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var item = list[i].Category;
       $scope.FCategory[item] = false;

    }
};
```

Comment: cat in (uniqueApplications = (applications | unique : 'Category')) I didn't know you could add things to a list at the markup level in that way! Thank you!